# I need a more reliable sort for CTE hierarchy query

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

Example table:

```
CREATE TABLE Fruit (
  ID int identity(1,1) NOT NULL,
  ParentID int NULL,
  Name varchar(255)
);
```

I want to sort parent and child records from the same table in alphabetical order (more than one level deep):

```
Apples
--Green
----Just Sour
----Really Sour        
--Red
----Big
----Small
Bananas
--etc.
```

I attempted this:

```
;WITH CTE(ID, ParentID, Name, Sort) AS
(
    SELECT 
         ID
        ,ParentID
        ,Name
        ,cast('\' + Name as nvarchar(255)) AS Sort          
    FROM Fruit
    WHERE ParentID IS NULL

    UNION ALL

    SELECT 
         a.ID
        ,a.ParentID
        ,a.Name
        ,cast(b.Sort + '\' + a.Name as nvarchar(255)) AS Sort           
    FROM Fruit a
    INNER JOIN CTE b ON a.ParentID = b.ID           
)
SELECT * FROM CTE Order by Sort
```

This produces results for the sort like:

```
\Apples
\Apples\Green
\Apples\Green\Just Sour
\etc.
```

Just when I thought things were good, it isn't reliable. For example, if an item has more than one word. Like:

```
\Apples
\Apples A <-- culprit
\Apples\Green
```

If I can expand my question while I'm at it, I'd like to show actual hyphens or something in the results:

```
Parent
- Child
--Grandchild
```

The cruddy way I quickly did this was by adding a prefix column in the table with the value of `-` for all records. Then I could do this:

```
;WITH CTE(ID, ParentID, Name, Sort, Prefix) AS
(
    SELECT 
         ID
        ,ParentID
        ,Name
        ,cast('\' + Name as nvarchar(255)) AS Sort  
        ,Prefix

    FROM Fruit
    WHERE ParentID IS NULL

    UNION ALL

    SELECT 
         a.ID
        ,a.ParentID
        ,a.Name
        ,cast(b.Sort + '\' + a.Name as nvarchar(255)) AS Sort
        ,cast(b.Prefix + a.Prefix as nvarchar(10)) AS Prefix


    FROM Fruit a
    INNER JOIN CTE b ON a.ParentID = b.ID           
)
SELECT * FROM CTE Order by Sort
```

But that seems incorrect or not optimal.

These hierarchical queries still give me a headache, so perhaps I'm just not seeing the obvious.

Comment: Well the problem is space ascii (32) go first than `'\'` ascii(92) what result are you expecting?

Comment: Doing this in SQL seems like a really poor design

Comment: @JoePhillips You mean better in the application? In my case I really need it done in the query.

Comment: I don't really mess with this functionality but it seems like you could change your recursive query to create something readable by FORXML() and then breakdown your hierarchies from here to sort them separately. I have no code to back that up though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tend to use row_number() ordered by Name in this case

**Example**

```
Declare @YourTable table (id int,ParentId  int,Name varchar(50))
Insert into @YourTable values 
 ( 1, NULL,'Apples')
,( 2, 1   ,'Green')
,( 3, 2   ,'Just Sour')
,( 4, 2   ,'Really Sour')
,( 5, 1   ,'Red')
,( 6, 5   ,'Big')
,( 7, 5   ,'Small')
,( 8, NULL,'Bananas')

Declare @Top    int         = null      --<<  Sets top of Hier Try 5 
Declare @Nest   varchar(25) = '|-----'  --<<  Optional: Added for readability

;with cteP as (
      Select Seq  = cast(1000+Row_Number() over (Order by Name) as varchar(500))
            ,ID
            ,ParentId 
            ,Lvl=1
            ,Name 
      From   @YourTable 
      Where  IsNull(@Top,-1) = case when @Top is null then isnull(ParentId ,-1) else ID end
      Union  All
      Select Seq  = cast(concat(p.Seq,'.',1000+Row_Number() over (Order by r.Name)) as varchar(500))
            ,r.ID
            ,r.ParentId 
            ,p.Lvl+1
            ,r.Name 
      From   @YourTable r
      Join   cteP p on r.ParentId  = p.ID)
Select A.ID
      ,A.ParentId 
      ,A.Lvl
      ,Name = Replicate(@Nest,A.Lvl-1) + A.Name
      ,Seq  --<< Can be removed
 From cteP A
 Order By Seq
```

**Returns**

```
ID  ParentId    Lvl Name                      Seq
1   NULL        1   Apples                    1001
2   1           2   |-----Green               1001.1001
3   2           3   |-----|-----Just Sour     1001.1001.1001
4   2           3   |-----|-----Really Sour   1001.1001.1002
5   1           2   |-----Red                 1001.1002
6   5           3   |-----|-----Big           1001.1002.1001
7   5           3   |-----|-----Small         1001.1002.1002
8   NULL        1   Bananas                   1002
```

Comment: Nice. Juan's answer worked great. This on the front seems more foolproof and removes any issues with the name itself. Testing it out in difference scenarios. Thank you for your help. I'll be back after some rigorous tests.

Comment: @user1447679 Juan's answer would never occur to me.  Lack of imagination on my part  :)

Comment: Okay... now I'll take back my statement about digging a hole for myself for not seeing the obvious. your lack of imagination eases my pain! I mean that in a joking manner of course.

Comment: @user1447679 This is why I love SO.  I learn something every day.  That's the fun part.

Comment: Although I figured the second part of my question (the naming with hyphens) prior to your answer, I accepted this one because technically it seems more sound, and answers my entire question, but kudos to Juan because it pushes me to think more creatively next time.

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to guess you want this result

```
\Apples
\Apples\Green
\Apples A
```

Maybe try something like this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM CTE 
ORDER BY replace(Sort, ' ', '~')
```

`'~'` is ascii 126, You can also check using excel sorting.

[image]

Comment: Oooo that's simply clever and should have been obvious.

Comment: Is the second part of my question staring at me in the face too? This may be a day to hide in a freshly dug hole for myself if it is.

Comment: Didn't saw the second part :P   Only need the first one to solve it.  What is wrong with the second query? Btw be carefull `~` is the biggest char on the 127 ascII, but if you string have characters fron extended ascii like `>=` you may need use `asci(254)`

Comment: Actually I'm sure I can figure it out by what you already suggested. Regardless, I'm going to dig my hole now.

Comment: Ohh I see now. Yes probably same principle. But not clear for me the exact result you want. Remember next time question require **both** sample data and expected output.